# Windows Phone 8 - Navigation Error

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I have a file in `IsolatedStorage`. If the file exists, I want to redirect to the login page or Create Account page.

If the file doesnt exist, the app goes to the Create page, a password is created and saved, and the app redirects to the Login page. However, if the file in IsolatedStorage exists, it won't direct.

```
private void fileExists()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (store.FileExists("passwordFile"))
            {
                //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                MessageBox.Show("Should be redirecting here");
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome. Please create an account. Ensure that you remember your password!");
            }
        }
```

The actual message does show so it's being called and if a file does not exist, the else is executed so my logic is sound.

The `FileExists()` function is called here.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fileExists();
        }
```

The other redirect happens here

```
if ((password1.Password == password2.Password) & (password1.Password.Trim().Length > 0 || password2.Password.Trim().Length > 0))
            {
                byte[] PasswordByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password1.Password);
                byte[] ProtectedPassword = ProtectedData.Protect(PasswordByte, null);
                this.WritePasswordToFile(ProtectedPassword);

                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
```

The error is a `System.NullReferenceException` but was not handled in user code.

Comment: real offtopic here, please hash or encrypt your passwordFile, with some fancy coding and modded WP8 it easily to access the isolatedStorage

Comment: I will be, it's literally just the start! I just started C# and WP yesterday and encryption is a big part of the project, but not something that I will be looking at for a few weeks. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Have tried to call the file exist check on MainPage load ? That can be storage preparing issue even if it is executing. Secondly if you can mention where the exact exception is occuring. Also do check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427601/nullreferenceexception-when-using-navigationservice) that might help you.

Comment: The file definitely exists. If I comment out the navigation part, it returns true and displays a message box, so the file is definitely there.

The exception is occurring in the fileExists() function at the navigation line (commented out above)

I will have a look through that link, seems good, but logically, I can't figure out why it should be causing an exception somewhere and not elsewhere, especially when other code runs fine.

Comment: Also do try to put the the check code in loaded event of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `NavigationService` is still null, you can verify that by putting a breakpoint on the redirect line,
put the same code in the `MainPage.Loaded` event and it will work then, (I expect it to work then)

as I expect this is only a redirect page you can check the file in the initialization and save uri to redirect in the class and redirect when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

I needed to move the fileExists() from the constructor to a new function.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            fileExists();
        }
```